# How to distribute and install on test devices an iOS app under development?

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I am new to iOS app development. I have a standard Apple iOS developer license. When I build my app it creates an `ipa` file. If I send this file to someone, will they be able to install it? Or does that require an enterprise license?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can share an `ipa` archive with testers/friends using [Ad Hoc Distribution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8-SW4). You do not need an enterprise license to do it, team or individual is enough. You will need to register a device's ID in the Member Center and to generate an Ad Hoc provisioning profile with this ID:

> Using this method, testers don’t need to be team members or iTunes
>   Connect users to run the app, but their devices need to be registered
>   in Member Center. You can register up to 100 devices per year that
>   your team can use for development and testing. Therefore, choose this
>   method if you can use a portion of these devices for testing and can
>   collect device IDs from testers. Also choose this method if you’re not
>   ready to create an app record in iTunes Connect. You don’t need to
>   validate or upload your app to iTunes Connect to distribute it using
>   an ad hoc provisioning profile.

Comment: The proviso being that you have a paid for developer account - either team or individual.   An enterprise account allows you to create `ipa`s that runs anywhere, but using it as a means to distribute or send test builds to third parties is against the terms and conditions of the account.

Answer (score 1):

As you have standard development licence, it's enough for distribution under 100 devices, and after one year, you can also remove previously registered devices from your member centre.

But as the answer above described, it should be ad hoc distribution only you can  use any except Apple Store distribution, so the easiest way to do that is to just  create a development provision with as many selected device as you want to distribute. After that, you just need to install a particular provision in your Mac by just clicking over it and then select the provision in your project.

1. Now compile your project.
2. After successful compilation, go to product folder, select the app, and reveal it in folder.
3. Copy the app file from this folder.
4. Just create one folder on your desktop and name it Payload.
5. Paste the app file you just copied inside the folder.
6. Place one image again on your desktop and name that iTunesArtwork but without extension.
7. Now select the payload folder and iTunesArtwork file together and compress it.
8. After compressing it, create archive.zip and rename it to may.ipa.
9. Now it will ask if you are sure you want to rename it. Press yes.

Now you have ipa read within few steps and you can use this payload and iTunesArtwork for making another .ipa or for any other project. Just leave this both folder and the file on your desktop. It will always help you.

Now go to http://diawi.com and upload your ipa file here which you just renamed,  and then when it's done with uploading, press the send button. It will give you a URL. Share it with your testers or friends. They can directly download it in their device. No need to send ipa, and in this process, no one can use re-engineering in your .ipa. It's safe and secure.